# how to resend a imessage containing URLs on IOS 12.4?

Tags: iphone

I can only execute the links but not copy the message.
I'm also able to copy a single link (but not the entire message).

Answer (score 1):

On a message, simply touch and press lightly while holding until **Copy** and **More** comes up at the bottom of the screen. Select **More**, then check the message(s) you want to resend and then in the lower right of the screen, tap the curved **arrow**. Fill in the **To** field and then send the new message.

Once you get used to the right touch pressure and holding it, this will become second nature for you.